# Tkinter entry.get() only works every 2 button clicks

Tags: python, tkinter

I was making a simple flashcard `tkinter` application and I've encountered a problem such that when I manage the subjects, only every second item is added to the file.

For example, say I went to the manage subject page and I wanted to add the subjects: `subject1`, `subject2`, `subject3`, `subject4`, ... `subjectN`.
The only subjects that would add to the file are the subjects with the odd endings, is there a fix for this?

The code responsible for this:

```
#subjects window
def managesubjectsF():
    def addF():
        f = open ('subjectlist.txt', 'a')
        f.write(addsubjectE.get() + '\n')
        f.close()
        addsubjectE.delete('0', 'end')
    subjectPage = Tk()
    subjectPage.title('Add subject')
    subjectPage.resizable(False, False)
    subjectPage.configure(background = 'light blue')
    subjectPage.geometry('260x70')
    addsubjectE = Entry(subjectPage, width=23, font=('bold', 14))
    addsubjectE.grid(column=1, row=1)
    addS = Button(subjectPage, text='Add', font=('bold', 15), command = addF)
    addS.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky = N)
```

Minimal example of implementation:

```
#modules
from tkinter import *
import os.path

#implementations
count=0
subjectlist = []

#main window details
root = Tk()
root.geometry('225x350')

#list of available subjects
choice = Listbox(root, font = ('bold', 15))
choice.grid(column=1, row=2)
if os.path.exists('./subjectlist.txt') == True:
    with open('subjectlist.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            count += 1
    f.close()
    f = open('subjectlist.txt', 'r')
    for i in range(count):
        choice.insert(END, (f.readline().strip()))
        subjectlist.append(f.readline().strip())
    f.close()
else:
    f = open('subjectlist.txt', 'w')
    f.close()
    
#subjects window
def managesubjectsF():
    def addF():
        f = open ('subjectlist.txt', 'a')
        f.write(addsubjectE.get() + '\n')
        f.close()
        addsubjectE.delete('0', 'end')
    subjectPage = Toplevel()
    subjectPage.geometry('260x70')
    addsubjectE = Entry(subjectPage, width=23, font=('bold', 14))
    addsubjectE.grid(column=1, row=1)
    addS = Button(subjectPage, text='Add', font=('bold', 15), command = addF)
    addS.grid(column=1, row=2, sticky = N)

#buttons
addsubjectsB = Button(root, text = 'Manage subjects', font = ('bold', 15), command = managesubjectsF)
addsubjectsB.grid(column=1, row=3, sticky = N)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dont call `tk.Tk()` more than once, use `tk.Toplevel` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, however changing it to tk.Toplevel still does not solve the problem posted

Comment: That can't be the entirety of you rcode — `mainloop()` is not called anywhere (and that's a requrement).

Comment: @Borntolol please provide a minimal reproducable exampel. Prima facie, I cant tell anything else.

Comment: Apologies, I usually leave that out until I wrap up my project as it is still functional without it in development stages.

Comment: I see two `f.readline()` in the code: `choice.insert(END, (f.readline().strip()))` then `subjectlist.append(f.readline().strip())`. Are the subjects in the file twice? If not, do one readline then store the value twice.

Comment: @Mike67 I think that this solves my problem, I completely forgot that it will move onto the next line even if used as an argument. Thank you!

Comment: You're problem was also related to calling `Tk()` more than once instead of using `Toplevel()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(moving comment to answer)

You are calling `readline` twice which is moving the file pointer and skipping subjects.

```
for i in range(count):
    choice.insert(END, (f.readline().strip()))
    subjectlist.append(f.readline().strip())  # reading next line
```

Try reading the value once then storing in both lists:

```
for i in range(count):
    s = f.readline().strip()  # read once
    choice.insert(END, (s))
    subjectlist.append(s)
```